# Click is not working during hover or mouseenter

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Mouseenter and Click combined</title>
</head>
<body>
<a id="linkselector" href="#">Click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {

//This is the click event
$('#linkselector').live('click',(function() {        

alert('You are clicked!');


}));

//This is the mouseover event
$('#linkselector').live('mouseenter', (function(evt){

    $('<div class="popupx"></div>').appendTo(document.body);
    $('.popupx').html('<img src="http://' + $(this).data('id') + '.jpg.to/">');
    $('.popupx').css({left: evt.pageX+30, top: evt.pageY-15}).show();
    $('.popupx').css('border','0');        

    $(this).live('mouseleave', (function(){
        $('.popupx').hide();
    }));
}));

});
```

And finally my CSS:

```
.popupx{
position:absolute;
width:30px;
height:30px;
}
.popupx img{
width:30px;
height:30px;
}
```

When I hover the link, the image correctly displays so its working. The problem is that when I click on it, it does not anymore trigger the click event. However if I remove the mouseenter/hover mechanism. The click event works fine.

How is it possible to have the click event fire when the user mouse over the link? Probably I miss something important in my code. Thanks for any tips.

**UPDATE**:  I have successfully combined the three events in one function but I'm still using LIVE and IF/else because for some reason ON won't work. Anyway, I have mouseenter and mouseleave working correctly in the logic below. But click still won't work when mouseenter is activated. Probably I need to find a way that the click event will fire when the hover or mouseenter event is still shown.

```
    $('#linkselector').live('click mouseleave mouseenter',(function(evt) {  

    if (evt.type === 'click') {
//This is a click event
    //This won't fire when the mouseenter or hover is shown

} else if (evt.type === 'mouseenter') { 

            //This is working nicely

        $('<div class="popupx"></div>').appendTo(document.body);
        $('.popupx').html('<img src="/image.png">');
        $('.popupx').css({left: evt.pageX-60, top: evt.pageY-60}).show();
        $('.popupx').css('border','0');

} else if (evt.type === 'mouseleave') {

         //This is also working nicely

        $('.popupx').remove();      

    }

}));
```

Comment: Any browser in particular? Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/QP5pt/

Comment: seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/dEuGM/

Comment: Yes its working right? But only on the fiddle but not on my application.. Thanks for the feedback. My browser is firefox 17.01 on Linux/Ubuntu.

Comment: Is it possible that the click event will fire even the mouseevent or hover image is still activated?

Comment: Just put a `console.log(evt.type);` at the very start of your function before all the `if..else` and post your results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine in jQuery 1.7.2 & firefox 17.
What is your jQuery version & browser?

I copy & paste your code here: 
jsfiddle.net/62Y64/

Comment: I have updated my question. Yes it is working but it does have some strange results on my actual application.

Answer (score 1):

Try a more modern approach, using `on()` and creating the elements with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on({
        click: function() {        
            alert('You are clicked!');
        },
        mouseenter: function(evt){
            $('<div />', {
                'class' : 'popupx',
                   html : '<img src="http://' + $(this).data('id') + '.jpg.to/">',
                  style : 'left: '+(evt.pageX+30)+'px; top: '+(evt.pageY-15)+'px; border: 0; display: block'
            }).appendTo($('body'));
        },
        mouseleave: function(){
            $('.popupx').remove();
        }
    }, '#linkselector');
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/QP5pt/1/)

`live()` is deprecated, and you should be using `on()`. It's also pretty clear from the code that everytime the link is hovered, a new element is created, then it's hidden when the mouse leaves, not removed, so you're creating a bunch of elements, one everytime the link is hovered, without ever removing them. You should probably replace `hide()` with `remove()`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm replace hide with remove, I checked on my Firebug and it indeed created a lot of elements. However it is strange that on won't work but live will work, I don't know about this. One question, how is it possible for the click event to fire when the mouseover or mouseevent is still activated? It is because my link is a link image and it shows another image during the hover.

Answer (score -1):

Bind them at the same time and then check which event it is.

```
$('#linkselector').live('mouseenter click', (function(evt) {
    if (evt.type === 'click') {
        alert('You are clicked!');
    } else {
        $('<div class="popupx"></div>').appendTo(document.body);
        $('.popupx').html('<img src="http://' + $(this).data('id') + '.jpg.to/">');
        $('.popupx').css({
            left: evt.pageX + 30,
            top: evt.pageY - 15
        }).show();
        $('.popupx').css('border', '0');

        $(this).live('mouseleave', (function() {
            $('.popupx').hide();
        }));
    }
}));
```

Comment: Would not recommend `if else` event handling. Extremely messy